# How to create a user-defined type assertion in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

How can one create a function that narrows the type of a variable (for static type checkers) in a similar way to `isinstance`?

For example, `ComplexTypeAssertion` just narrows the type at runtime but not for static checks:

```
def MyFunction(myData: object) -> object:
  if isinstance(myData, list):
    reveal_type(myData)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.list[Any]'
  if ComplexTypeAssertion(myData):   # <<< How to make MyPy understand this?
    reveal_type(myData)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.object'

def ComplexTypeAssertion(data: object) -> bool:
    return isinstance(data, list) and all(isinstance(value, str) for value in data)
```

How could I define `ComplexTypeAssertion` such that static analysis tools would understand the type?

Obviously, this is a toy example, real life examples would be more complex. It would be very useful in situations where I want to assert that some data follows a `TypedDict` construct or other typing constructs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mypy generally only understands a few specific ways of narrowing a type, such as using `isinstance` or `if x is not None`. However, in Python >=3.10, [PEP 647](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/) provides a solution to this problem with the new `typing.TypeGuard` feature. Now, you are able to write your `ComplexTypeAssertion` function like so, and type checkers will understand that `data` is guaranteed to be of type `list[str]` if the function returns `True`:

```
from typing import TypeGuard

def ComplexTypeAssertion(data: object) -> TypeGuard[list[str]]:
    return isinstance(data, list) and all(isinstance(value, str) for value in data)
```

`TypeGuard` is also available for Python <3.10 via the semi-official [`typing-extensions` library on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/), which provides backports of newer typing constructs to earlier versions of Python. (If you're using Mypy, you'll find that `typing-extensions` is already a dependency of Mypy, so importing something from `typing-extensions` won't even necessarily mean that you have to add an additional dependency to your project.)

Comment: Excellent! By updating `typing-extensions` to ~3.10, it allows me to use TypeGuard in previous versions of Python as well.

Comment: @PhilMacKay fantastic!