# Asserting a variable has certain properties if it passes certain tests

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, duck-typing

Using the python typing system, I sometimes know the type of a variable or an expression because I have installed runtime checking to verify it.  Is there a way to denote this with annotations?

For example, suppose I have a function `combop` which returns `True` if its argument is of class `Combination`.   And further suppose that the class `Combination` has a field called `tds`.

```py
if combop(x):
   return f(x.tds)
else:
   return f([])
```

In this example, I'd like to promise the checker that within the then part of the if, that `x` has type `Combination`, and `x.tds` makes sense.

An example of such a situation is line 172 of [here python-rte](https://gitlab.lrde.epita.fr/jnewton/python-rte/-/blob/62ababf09adb5e6b14638898c467bd190c1ced9f/pyrte/genus/s_combination.py#L172).  The IDE complains about `d.tds` and also `n.s`.  I am supposing that there is a way to explain my intentions with type annotations, and the IDE would accept or verify my claim if possible.

The way this is done in some functional languages (e.g. Scala) is with pattern matching.  Within a clause of a pattern match the type inferencer is able to restrict the type of certain variables.  In some other languages (e.g. Common Lisp) there is a `declare` syntax which allows the programmer to give hints to the type inferencer which may or may not contribute a run-time overhead, depending on compiler settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a user-defined type assertion in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002167/is-it-possible-to-create-a-user-defined-type-assertion-in-python)

Comment: @AlexWaygood, I'm not sure whether that answers my question or not.  It seems to me like a pretty bizarre way to address the problem.   I was thinking there'd be a way to make some annotation to promise that x of some type for which `.tds` makes sense.

Comment: Python's type checkers aren't as sophisticated as those in more statically typed languages, so things which are fairly easy to notate in Scala are often going to be more complex to notate in python. I'll see if I can write up some ideas in an answer in a bit.

Comment: There's also the fact that Python's typing system is still very new, so the syntax is still very much being figured out. It may be that in time, the language adopts a lot more of the ideas found in Scala. https://github.com/python/typing/issues/813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.10 will introduce the new [`TypeGuard`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/) feature, which *might* provide you with what you're looking for. (The feature is also available through the [typing_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module for Python <= 3.9.) A `TypeGuard` allows you to assert to the type-checker that an object is of a certain type. So, you could write a function like this:

```
from typing import TypeGuard, Any

def combop(obj: Any) -> TypeGuard[Combination]:
    # Some code that returns `True` if the object is of type `Combination`, else `False`.
```

If you're more interested in the *properties* of your object (the "structural type" as opposed to the "nominal type" of your object), then you could use a `TypeGuard` to assert that your object conforms to a certain [protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/).

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeGuard, Any

class CombinationsProto(Protocol):
    tds: list[Any]


def combops(obj: Any) -> TypeGuard[CombinationsProto]:
    # Some code here that returns `True` if the object has a `tds` attribute, else `False`.
```

As this is a new feature in the python-typing world, Python's major type-checkers are still working on support for this feature, especially with respect to some complex [corner](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5406https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/5406) [cases](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9927).

Comment: just a question of clarification.   `TypeGuard` seems to work very well.  Do you know whether `filter` is compatible with `TypeGuard`?  For example, if `x` has type `List[X]`, and `combop` is declared returning `TypeGuard[Combination]` as you suggest, then mypy seems to think that `list(filter(combop,x))` has type `List[X]` rather than `List[Combination]`.  Do you think that is what is to be expected?

Comment: @JimNewton that sounds unfortunate. I'm not sure whether that's (a) because it's a new feature, and MyPy is still working through some corner cases with respect to how they implement it, or (b) how it's always going to work. Unless it's already been asked, I might file a bug report with MyPy to ask for clarification?

Comment: Looks like there's no editor support just yet
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-49040

Comment: @JimNewton that seems to be a bug report for Pycharm, no? MyPy isn't a JetBrains product, and is implemented differently to pycharm's type-checker. (It's also generally a lot less buggy!)

Comment: @JimNewton this looks more relevant imo https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9927

Answer (score -2):

```py
import typing


class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bar = "zebra"  # will be of 'str' type


def give_me_something():  # no annotation here, can't tell what gets returned
    if dict():  # an empty dict is always False, this is just an example, a real condition could be used
        return []
    else:
        return Foo()


reveal_type(give_me_something())
reveal_type(typing.cast(Foo, give_me_something()))
```

```
$ mypy so69205255.py
so69205255.py:16: note: Revealed type is "Any"
so69205255.py:17: note: Revealed type is "so69205255.Foo"
```

I used MyPy to reproducibly check, but my IDE PyCharm also understands it : when I hover the variable name I assigned the expression to, it says that the first one is of type `Union[list, Foo]` while the second is of type `Foo`.

More info : see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast)

Comment: sorry but I don't see how your post addresses my question.   I've read it a couple of times.   It seems off topic to me.

Comment: The `typing.cast` is a convention to instruct the type checker which is the type of a variable.

Comment: Do you mean type of a variable or type of an expression?  I.e., it is only valid to cast a variable but not an intermediate expression?  When I look at the documentation https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html, it does not say explicitly that this applies only to variables, however, the only examples shown are variable definitions.

Comment: @JimNewton semantically, `cast` is a no-op, it only returns the value it was given. But it is a **marker** for type checkers (either MyPy or the one in your IDE) to **assume** the value is of the specified type. So `cast(int, "foo")` is considered an int, because `cast` said so. That was what I wanted to show in my answer, which I failed to make you understand. You asked "I'd like to promise the checker that [...] x has type Combination", `cast` is the answer. Indeed, in the examples it only used in assignations, but it can be used anywhere, like I did in my answer's example.